# app submited in app store getting issues

Tags: ios, app-store

We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "MyApp". Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery:

Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '76x76' pixels, in .png format.

Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '152x152' pixels, in .png format.

this warning came from apple store when I'm submitted my App in apple store

Comment: Short answer: Do as Apple says. You should read & follow the app store submission checklist.

Comment: The answer is in your question

Comment: where i have place 76 x 76 and 152x152 pixels pixels image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple message is correct. You have to put icon file and define in plist under icons section with both the resolution.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I hope you uploaded the app from xcode 4.5.There you can see the 76*76 & 152*152 icon spaces.There you might miss to add iamges

Comment: here i'm using  xcode 4.5

Answer (score 1):

The message is correct from Apple.

This problem arrises if you have submitted with some missing icon files in your plist.

If you are using xcode5 with ios7 you can see the icon files in your project required to submit the app to appstore.

This new icon files with their mentioned dimensions need to be added in your plist if you submit the app to the appstore.

So submit your app with these app icon sizes and you are ready to go.